# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Whenever I run AWS server with two simple python scripts doing HTTP Requests using screen as background tasks, the AWS Server runs fine for 1 hour so, after that when i try to log back onto the SSH I get error ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer and always have to stop the instance and run again, then log into ssh with new IP. I don't get what the problem is. Does this happen to anyone?

Comment: If you monitor an SSH client, you will notice (at least on my system connecting to AWS) that the connection is reset every 60 minutes. My SSH client Bitvise handles this and automatically reconnects. I will bet that this is related to SSH Rekey and your system is setup for 60 minutes. Changing the rekey time is not a good idea, it would be better to correctly handle this in your code. Q) are you sure that you need to stop / start the instance? If you just restart you will get the same IP address, whereas stop then start sometimes changes the IP address. A restart should not be required.

Comment: You also may need to send an SSH keepalive. You will need to implement this in your code but this article talks about keelives: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley thanks for ur reply. Restart does still give me error, only stop/start makes it work. I will look into what u linked

Comment: I misread your question. At first glance I thought that you were making SSH requests in your code. The issue with stop versus restart does not make sense. Check to see if your instance is running out of memory or becoming CPU locked. Your issue sounds like SSHD on the instance is crashing. Try enabling logging when SSHD is started and then review the logs after a failure.

Comment: I believe you need to monitor memory consumption of your scripts over time.  An out of memory condition might be reasonably expected to prevent new SSH connections.